# how to animate the wheel with Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

When I try animate the wheel, I have problem.
You can see this in the **[example](https://codepen.io/webslavik/pen/PJqLKz?editors=1010)**.

I read **[article](http://www.bentedder.com/using-snap-svg-javascript-to-build-animated-car/)** and try wrote code, but maybe I missed something.

```
function moveWheels() {
 wheel_right_needles.animate({ transform: 'r0 ' + 
  getCenterPoint(wheel_right_needles) });

 setTimeout(function() {
  wheel_right_needles.animate({ transform: 'r90 ' + 
  getCenterPoint(wheel_right) }, 1000, function() {
    moveWheels();
  });
 }, 300);
}

moveWheels();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm no expert in SVG animations in the browser, but adding a quick console.log to the movewheels function (inside your timeOut, line 187) suggests that the getCenterpoint of wheel_right is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed it. here is a fiddle ([click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbc9teau/))  you can check

I changed the function as below:

```
function moveWheels() {
   var c=getCenterPoint(wheel_right_needles);    
    wheel_right_needles.transform("r0," + c);  
     wheel_right_needles.animate({ transform: 'r360 ' + c }, 1000, function()  {
       moveWheels();
    });
}
```

Also, i noticed wheel animation works on previous version of snapsvg 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js